# How to add different condition using json decode

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$firstArray= [
    [
        "ID" => "ABC"
    ],
    [
        "ID" => "100"
    ],
    [
        "ID" => "200"
    ]
];

$firstArray= ["ABC" =>"fail"];

**Here I have to check two condition**
```

> Condition #1

`$abc` i am having 3 values, out of this values suppose present in `$second` array,we have ignore the value and remaining only one value we have to assign  `$existarray`

As of now i have completed it is working fine also,

> Condition #2

I have one more json like this

```
$jsonString = '{
    "jsonData" : {
        "ABC" : {
            "Count" :1
        },
         "100" : {
            "Count" :3
        },
        "200" : {
            "Count" :1
        }
    }
}';
$finalcount= json_decode($jsonString);
```

Now i want to check one more condition `$abc` array of `mainarray` key values count **<10** we should ignore.This condition i have to implement my current code

> Expected output

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 200
 )
```

Comment: Why ID 200 is in expected output? its attempt count is less then 3 so doesn't it need to be ignore?

Comment: Same is true for ID 100 (notice the smaller or **equal** to 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merging 2 condition in if statement is done with `&&`.

You can just mix those 2 condition in 1 for-loop:

```
$jsonString = '{"jsonData" : {
        "ABC" : {"Count" :1},
        "100" : {"Count" :3},
        "200" : {"Count" :1}
    }
}';
$firstArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$hobbies= [["ID" => "ABC"],["ID" => "100"],["ID" => "200"]];
$books= ["ABC" => true];

foreach ($Response as $key => $value) {
    $id = $value['ID'];
    if (!isset($books[$id]) && $firstArray["jsonData"][$id]["Count"] < 3 ) {
        $selectedItem = $value;
        break;
    }
}
```